# Smallest set of couples in [n] stable by permutations

Tags: co.combinatorics, permutations

I am dealing with the following problem :

I need to create the smallest possible set $\{(x_i,y_i) \in [n]^2, x_i\neq y_i\}$ for $n$ given, such that :

$\forall p \in \mathcal{S}_n, \exists i,j$ such that $p(x_i)=x_j$ and $p(y_i)=y_j$.

What I tried to do was, for a given set, express the number of permutations covered by all the couples, but then I need to pick the couples so that I will minimize the intersections between the $(n-2)!$ permutations each time.

Has this problem been encountered before, or would you have any idea on how I could find the optimal set ? Sorry if I'm not being clear, I already have problems expressing the problem simply. Thank you in advance !

Edit : An example, for $n=3$ : With the set {(1,2),(2,1),(3,2),(1,3)}, I can cover all the permutations :

$e$ : (1,2) is sent to (1,2)

$(12)$ : (1,2) is sent to (2,1)

$(13)$ : (1,2) is sent to (3,2)

$(23):$ (1,2) is sent to (1,3)

$(123)$ : (1,3) is sent to (2,1)

$(132)$ : (1,3) is sent to (3,2)

And this is actually the smallest cardinality I can have to verify the condition.

Comment: @coudy Sorry, the $x_i$ are not necessarily distinct, only the couples are. By [n] I mean the integers from 1 to $n$, and the smallest set is the set which has the smallest cardinality.

Comment: Any set of size strictly greater than $(n^2-n)/2$ will work. (Pigeonhole: the sizes of the sets $A$ and $pA$ add up to more than $n^2-n$, so they have to intersect.) For $n=3$, any set of $4$ pairs will work; for $n=4$, any set of $7$ pairs will work. Do you know what is the actual smallest size for $n=4$?

Comment: @ZachTeitler Thanks. For $n=4$ the minimum is 4 too. I'm actually trying to prove that the minimal cardinality is greater than $2n-4$ $\forall n$. I wrote a script that was able to test it until $n=12$ only.

Comment: If you post as an answer what you believe minimal sets are for some n, you or someone else can look up in OEIS for possible earlier references.  Gerhard "Indexing Concepts By Number Sequence" Paseman, 2017.04.04.

Comment: Why are you trying to prove $2n-4$? The best general construction I see is to take $(1,i)$ and $(i,1)$ for each $i>1$, in total $2n-2$ pairs. This works because one can take $(1,p^{-1}(1))$ and $(p(1),1)$ if $p(1)\ne 1$, and $(1,p^{-1}(2))$ and $(1,2)$ otherwise.

Comment: @domotorp I'm trying to prove a graph theory conjecture saying that every digraph with less than $2n-4$ edges admits a packing with itself, and it's equivalent to say that every of those sets with cardinality $2n-4$ does not cover all the permutations, this is why only the minimum value is interesting in this case. I thought it would be easier to see it this way but I guess not.

Comment: @Alice I'm just trying to understand why $2n-4$ and not $2n-2$ is the value you're trying to prove. If I understood your graph theory problem well, even there $2n-2$ seems to be the natural lower bound. Do you have a lower bound of size $2n-4$? Btw, if I were you, I would add this interesting connection to packing digraphs as a motivation to the question.